# PL/SQL Block, Sql Plus ORDER BY Statement on a Column Populated by a Sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, sequence

Does anyone know why the ORDER BY operation not work on a column populated by a sequence?

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicles (
  veh_ID VARCHAR2(10),
  make VARCHAR2(30),
  PRIMARY KEY (veh_ID));

CREATE SEQUENCE veh_ID_seq
  MINVALUE 1
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 20;
```

I have a column named veh_ID that is populated by a sequence to increment by 1 through a PL/SQL Block. After the table is populated, I use this script:

```
SELECT (*) 
FROM Vehicles 
ORDER BY veh_ID;
```

The results return the veh_ID column out of order. But if I remove the ORDER BY from the script, the table is displayed with the veh_ID in sequential order.

**Expected Output:**

```
veh_ID  make     
-------------------         
1       Cheverolet
2       Ford
3       Dodge
4       GMC
5       Toyota
6       Honda
7       Jeep
```

**Actual Output:**

```
veh_ID  make     
-------------------         
6       Honda
2       Ford
3       Dodge
5       Toyota
7       Jeep
1       Cheverolet
4       GMC
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `(*)` makes no sense. A simple `*` will work just as fine.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data and the output you get. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments). You need to explain what you mean with "out of order"

Comment: give us the table definition as well (DDL) - I don't know of any circumstance where it would order a number, char, or varchar2 string as you show.

Comment: If VEH_ID gets its value from a sequence, why is its datatype VARCHAR2? Apart from that, I don't know how to say it politely, but - I don't believe what you claim. SELECT you posted, as well as both outputs are *fabricated*. Please, prove me wrong and post *exact* copy/paste of your SQL*Plus session which shows what you're saying.